# Perl vSphere SDK adding multiple disks soap error:

Tags: perl, vmware, vsphere

I am able to add the disks linearly like below:

```
my $vmSpec = VirtualMachineConfigSpec->new(deviceChange => [$devSpecs[0]]);
$vmView->ReconfigVM(spec => $vmSpec);
my $vmSpec = VirtualMachineConfigSpec->new(deviceChange => [$devSpecs[1]]);
$vmView->ReconfigVM(spec => $vmSpec);
my $vmSpec = VirtualMachineConfigSpec->new(deviceChange => [$devSpecs[2]]);
$vmView->ReconfigVM(spec => $vmSpec);
```

However, when I attempt to add all the disks at once I get a SOAP fault

```
my $vmSpec = VirtualMachineConfigSpec->new(deviceChange => \@devSpecs);
$vmView->ReconfigVM(spec => $vmSpec);
```

The Error:

```
SOAP Fault:
-----------
Fault string: Cannot complete the operation because the file or folder
/vmfs/volumes/ba5e81fe-201a6c4e/paul-vm1/paul-vm1_0_3.vmdk already exists
Fault detail: FileAlreadyExists
```

Is there anyone out there wise in the way of VSphere/VMware that knows what is going on?

EDIT : The file definitely does not exist before or after I run the code.

Comment: The error isn't clear?

Comment: @ jordanm I should have said that the file does not exists, adding that to my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.  Apparently you need to give each virtual machine config spec its own key, even if it is negative.  For posterity set

```
$disk->key = UNIQUE NEGATIVE NUMBER
```

and then set your config spec

```
$devSpec = VirtualDeviceConfigSpec->new(
      operation     => $devSpec->operation,
      fileOperation => $devSpec->fileOperation,
      device        => $disk,
);
```